# Python recursive function call with if statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement, recursion

I have a question regarding function-calls using if-statements and recursion.
I am a bit confused because python seems to jump into the if statements block even if my function returns "False"

Here is an example:

```
1    def function_1(#param):
2       if function_2(#param):
3           #do something
4           if x<y:
5               function_1(#different parameters)
6           if x>y:
7               function_1(#different parameters)
```

My function_2 returns "False" but python continues the code on line 5 for example. Can anyone explain this behavior? Thanks in advance for any answers.

edit: Sorry, forgot the brackets

concrete example:

```
1    def findExit(field, x, y, step):
2        if(isFieldFree(field, x, y)):
3            field[y][x] = filledMarker
4            findExit(field, x + 1, y, step+1)
5            findExit(field, x - 1, y, step+1)
6            findExit(field, x, y + 1, step+1)
7            findExit(field, x, y - 1, step+1)
8        elif(isFieldEscape(field, x, y)):
9            way.append(copy.deepcopy(field))
10            wayStep.append(step+1)

    def isFieldFree(field, x, y):
        if field[y][x] == emptyMarker:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def isFieldEscape(field, x, y):
        if field[y][x] == escapeMarker:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

After both functions "isFieldFree" and "isFieldEscape" return False python continues the code in line 5 sometimes in line 6.

Comment: `if function_2:` Are you sure this is what you meant? is function_2 is a function?

Comment: Without a more concrete example, can't really help. From above if `function_2()` returns `False` then the recursion ends.

Comment: @AChampion Thank you for your reply, added a concrete example. It is an example for solving a maze using recursive function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may misunderstand how recursion works, yes it continues at line 5 or 6 because the recursion has ended at a lower level in the call stack, so it continues at a higher-level in the call stack. Here's a sample call stack, note the next operation after `False` is the next `findExit()` at the higher call stack:

```
1 findExit(...):
2    True:
3        field assignment
4.1      findExit(x+1) 
  2          True
  3              field assignment
  4.1            findExit(x+1):
    2                False  # Does not jump to line 5 in current call stack.
  5.1            findExit(x-1):
    .                ...
```

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:**

That's because you're not actually calling the function. You can call the function by using the parenthesis.

```
if function2():
    ...
```

**Long answer:**

Functions in Python are a first class citizen (functional paradigm), and so it is completely valid to refer to a function just by its name. The following is valid syntax:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello")

hello_sayer = hello
hello_sayer() # print "Hello"
```

The next concept in play is truth-ness of non-Boolean variables.
In Python, the following are considered False-y

- None
- False
- zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
- any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
- any empty mapping, for example, {}. instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines
- a **nonzero**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the
  integer zero or bool value False.

Everything else is True-ish. Since a function name falls under none of the above categories, it is considered True-ish when tested in a conditional context.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

**Edit**: The earlier question was incomplete, and did not have a function call. For the new question, AChampion's answer is the correct one.

Comment: Updated so the documentation link uses Python 3. Python 2.4 is way too old to reference.

Comment: Note: OP updated question and this doesn't address his actual issue.